# React - filter props by object property on click

Tags: reactjs

I have my main component in which I'm fetching github repositories api, putting it into component's state then passing the data to another component ("SecondComponent") through props.

"SecondComponent" renders list of buttons which should allow me to filter the repos props by language (display repos with language equals to button's id). The component also should render filtered repos list (another component).

[image]

The screen certainly explains problem better than me.

In which component should I apply a function of filtering the props?

Here's the code:

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import "./App.css";
const REPOURL =
  "https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=stars:%3E1&sort=stars&order=desc&type=Repositories";

class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      reps: [],
      langs: ["All", "JavaScript", "Ruby", "Java", "CSS", "Python"]
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch(REPOURL)
      .then(result => result.json())
      .then(data => this.setState({ reps: data.items }));
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <main>
        <h1>Repositiories</h1>
        <SecondComponent langs={this.state.langs} reps={this.state.reps} />
      </main>
    );
  }
}

class SecondComponent extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <ul>
          {this.props.langs.map(l => (
            <button onClick={this.handleClick} id={l}>
              {l}
            </button>
          ))}
          <ReposList reps={this.props.reps} />
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class ReposList extends Component {
  repoToRepoItem = repo => {
    const name = repo.name;
    const owner_avatar_url = repo.owner.avatar_url;
    const owner_html_url = repo.html_url;
    const owner_login = `@${repo.owner.login}`;
    const stargazers_count = `${repo.stargazers_count} stars`;
    return (
      <RepoItem
        name={name}
        owner_avatar_url={owner_avatar_url}
        owner_html_url={owner_html_url}
        owner_login={owner_login}
        stargazers_count={stargazers_count}
      />
    );
  };
  render() {
    if (this.props.reps.length > 0)
      return (
        <ul className="items-container">
          {this.props.reps.map(this.repoToRepoItem)}
        </ul>
      );
    return <p>No results...</p>;
  }
}

const RepoItem = ({
  name,
  owner_avatar_url,
  owner_html_url,
  owner_login,
  stargazers_count
}) => {
  return (
    <li key={name}>
      <img className="avatar" src={owner_avatar_url} alt={name} />
      <h3>
        <a href={owner_html_url}>{name}</a>
      </h3>
      <h4>{owner_login}</h4>
      <p>{stargazers_count}</p>
    </li>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In which component should I apply a function of filtering the props?

You need to have a state of which button was clicked within `SecondComponent`.
say, `this.state = {selectedLanguages: []}`

And then you need to pass the selected language in the code below

```js
{this.props.langs.map(l => (
            <button onClick={this.handleClick} id={l}>
              {l}
            </button>
          ))}
```

by passing the event value to `this.handleClick` to save the language to the clicked state list.

```js
<button onClick={e => this.handleClick(e)} id={l}>
```

Then instead of mapping over `this.props.langs`, you need to filter it before mapping over it.

Something like following (not tested).

```js
render() {
    const {langs} = this.props;
    const {selectedLanguages} = this.state;

    // filter only if anything's selected else show all
    const languages = selectedLanguages.length === 0 
        ? langs 
        : langs.filter(lang => selectedLanguages.includes(lang));

    return (
        <div>
        <ul>
            {languages.map(l => (
            <button onClick={this.handleClick} id={l}>
                {l}
            </button>
            ))}
            <ReposList reps={this.props.reps} />
        </ul>
        </div>
    );
}
```

I could written the whole code myself, but left the rest for you to have fun with

*Just my $0.02. Not related to the question but I believe `SecondComponent` might need to be renamed more explicitly like `FilterableRepoList`, etc..*

Comment: Thank you! Indeed I've renamed component! :)